# Is there a way to make angular 2/4 material tab widths be based on the length of the label instead of cutting off?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am using angular2 material, I have the issue where some of my tab titles are long, which cuts off the icon that is at the end of the title text. (a small x). In my code below, notice how some of the tabs do not have an x to the right due to the tabs cutting off. Is there some way to make it so that the tab is sized so that it displays the entire label?

I prefer not to do a limitTo or reduce the length of the tab title.

```
<md-tab-group>
  <md-tab>
    <ng-template md-tab-label>
        Name of a Tab 1
        <md-icon>close</md-icon>
    </ng-template>    
    Content 1
  </md-tab>
  <md-tab>
    <ng-template md-tab-label>
        The naming of tab is so long 2
        <md-icon>close</md-icon>
    </ng-template>    
    Content 1
  </md-tab>
  <md-tab>
    <ng-template md-tab-label>
        Name of a Tab 3
        <md-icon>close</md-icon>
    </ng-template>    
    Content 1
  </md-tab>  
  <md-tab>
    <ng-template md-tab-label>
        Name of a Tab 4
        <md-icon>close</md-icon>
    </ng-template>    
    Content 1
  </md-tab>  
  <md-tab>
    <ng-template md-tab-label>
        Long Name Of Some Tab 5
        <md-icon>close</md-icon>
    </ng-template>    
    Content 1
  </md-tab>    
  <md-tab>
    <ng-template md-tab-label>
        This is a special tab 6
        <md-icon>close</md-icon>
    </ng-template>    
    Content 1
  </md-tab>    
</md-tab-group>
```

I have a plunkr that illustrates my issue:
    https://plnkr.co/edit/sjrZAiKg3ZdAq8xvGuPp?p=preview

If this is not possible, that is an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your problem, add the following code to your `styles.css` file on the root of your app:

```
.mat-tab-label {
    display: flex;
}
```

This is a plunkr with the fix:

[Angular 2 Material Demo for tab with close icon - Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/W2e3pkOOsvQoH7Mlj4NE?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

If you write the the Accepted code in style.css, it will affect all the tabs of your app. If you want to use it component specific, write :host and ::ng-deep beforehand. Example-

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-tab-label {
    display: flex;
}
```